# Reposition jQueryUI dialog from inside the dialog

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

**SOLVED - Waiting two days for self-accept**

Using a jQueryUI dialog to display a data entry form.

When user clicks NEXT, the dialog size is changed (several controls are added) and I wish to reposition the dialog to the top of the window.

The NEXT button is evaluated inside the `buttons{}` area of .dialog:

```
$('#new_contact').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    title: 'Enter contact information:',
    width: 800,
    buttons: {
        Next: function() {
            var vet = verify_dialog_fields();

            if (second_time_thru == 0) {
==> ==> ==>     $('#new_contact').dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );
                ask_choose_projects();
                return false;
            }
--= SNIP! =--
```

**The dialog is not being repositioned**, so either the `position` command is wrong or I've something else wrong.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong from this *incomplete* code snippet?

I suspect that I've done something wrong since I'm calling .dialog("option") inside .dialog() itself.

At the least, I need confirmation that the `position` option, identified by the three arrows, is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense that one cannot change a dialog's options from inside the initialization of the dialog itself, but this work-around did the trick.

It is admittedly a kludge, but it worked:

1. Create a dummy `<span id="dummy"></span>` element in the main document
2. Add jQuery code to reposition the form if the `#dummy` span is clicked
3. In the function for the `Next:` button, trigger a click on the #dummy element.

New HTML:

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
```

Revised code for NEXT function:

```
$('#new_contact').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal:true,
    title: 'Enter contact information:',
    width: 800,
    buttons: {
        Next: function() {
            var vet = verify_dialog_fields();

            if (second_time_thru == 0) {
==> ==> ==>     $('#dummy').trigger('click');
                ask_choose_projects();
                return false;
            }
--= SNIP! =--
```

New jQuery code:

```
$('#dummy').click(function() {
    $('#new_contact').dialog( "option", "position", 'top' );
});
```